# Acpid: cannot execute action script

Tags: scripts, services, systemd, acpi

I have a Thinkpad x200 Tablet and I want to rotate the screen when the display is twisted. Acpid seemed the easiest tool for this, so I created the event files in /etc/acpi/events :

```
event=video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001
action=/etc/acpi/TBLTmode.sh
```

and the script file with all permissions (chmod a+wrx) in /etc/acpi:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate inverted
xsetwacom --set "14" rotate half
xsetwacom --set "15" rotate half
xsetwacom --set "16" rotate half
```

The script executed fine in foreground, but when the acpid exectue it, the script not doing anything (the screen and the cursor stay their states). Here is what journalctl said:

```
acpid[9793]: received input layer event "video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001"
acpid[9793]: rule from /etc/acpi/events/TBLTmode matched
acpid[10272]: executing action "/etc/acpi/TBLTmode.sh"
acpid[9793]: action exited with status 255
acpid[9793]: 1 total rule matched
acpid[9793]: completed input layer event "video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008 00000001"
```

I have already checked that the exit status is 255 (Tried the exit 0 command in the end of the script), it not helped.